# Install a Windows on Dell laptop

Tags: boot, windows-10, usb, drivers, dell-inspiron

I've bought a Dell laptop with some branded crap preinstalled in its Windows 10 OEM. It's Inspiron 7559 and I wanted to get a real Windows 10 Pro system, since Arch (the system I hoped to use on daily basis) doesn't yet play well with its HDPI screen. And well it just stopped booting after some reboots

So I took the media creation tool from Microsoft and made a bootable USB stick which does indeed boot on my Dell, but it just can't install Windows 10, here is what happens:

I enter all the prerequisites, choose the partitions etc. It starts to install and... just stuck on the `getting files ready for whatever (67%)`

The solution is obviously https://communities.intel.com/thread/96603?tstart=0

But I just can't get the steps.

I've tried the solution suggested by Intel forums to no avail. I've also tried installing newest Ubuntu with similar results. It seems that Dell sold me a brick.

- What exact "Intel Drivers" shall I get extracted to my boot USB stick? Am I supposed to search the internet for them?
- What is a "Data Partition" and why should I format it?
- Where is the button to load the additional drivers that I got from internet?
- How am I supposed to update the BIOS if I don't have a Windows PC?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by a "real" Windows 10 Professional installation?  **What exact "Intel Drivers"** the Intel drivers supplied by Dell.  **What is a "Date Partition" and why shall I format it?** I presume you actually mean *Data Partition*, if so, update your question.  **How am I supposed to update bios if I have not a windows PC?** Follow the instructions supplied by Dell.  *Update your question it has far to many tiny mistakes.*

Comment: [You can use this tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility), or manually stripstream your required device drivers, to the .WIM files that reside on the .ISO yourself.  Due the nature of the tool it should work for any version of Windows, if not, follow the manual instructions in the read me and adapt them to Windows 10.

Comment: Please post your Dell service tag number so we can find drivers for that model.

Comment: @Moab No thx, I won't go that route. I think you shall be responsible for what you sell, hence I'll stay public

Comment: @Ramhound question was kindly edited by SU, Your tool helps with USB 3.0 and contains no instructions for other drivers

Comment: @rostamn739 - So you won't provide the information, required to find you the drivers, so we can answer your question.  That means we can't help you.  The tool doesn't care what drivers you choose to add to the .wim.  ReadMe tells you how to add drivers yourself to the .wim

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I got you wrong, I thought about a ticket in your CRM or something like that. Never had to contact Dell support before. Here is my service tag: 9XD3L82